# Raising errors on failed custom validations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote a custom validation to error out once a user attempts to withdraw more than the minimum allowed withdrawal amount. The validation fails as it should when the user's withdrawal is below the minimum allowed amount but the code continues running. It does not act like regular validations on model fields.

```
validate :minimum_withdrawal_amount, on: :create
validates :amount, numericality: {greater_than: 0}

def minimum_withdrawal_amount
    if sum.nil? || sum < currency.min_withdraw_amount
      errors.add :base, -> { I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.withdraw.amount.min_withdraw_amount', currency: currency.key, amount: currency.min_withdraw_amount ) }
    end
  end
```

It goes ahead and validates the amount that comes after it. If that validation fails, it then errors out. I'll like my custom validation to act like the validation on `amount`. Hope I'm clear enough

Comment: What is `currency_obj`? The code looks fine, Can you go to console and create a record with bang sign (eg: `User.create!`) and see whether there is your custom validation or not?

Answer (score 0):

Following replacement might work for you:
errors.add(:base, I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.withdraw.amount.min_withdraw_amount', currency: currency.key, amount: currency.min_withdraw_amount ))